# Card flipping by css transform, which properties need animation?

Tags: css

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mpegaejL/1/)**

The core of the flipping animation is on `transform: rotateY(180deg);`.  Of course `transition` is needed as well for animation.  I copied the code from another site, which uses `transition: all ...;`.

For some reason, some properties (eg: height, width) must have no transition.  But I don't know which properties are essential for flipping animation.

Anyone knows how I can change the line `transition: all ...;`  to keep the flipping animation, while not affecting unrelated properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page explains everything and has live demos. I've just needed a simple Google search. :)

http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html

Apparently, the trick is to use

> transition: transform 1s;

Comment: You are right.  I did not realise that `transform` is a property, although it is even written in the code I pasted.

Comment: I didn't know about it too before searching for this answer, hehe.

Answer (score 0):

change the style when you `:hover` on parent

```css
.card {
    -moz-perspective: 600;
    -webkit-perspective: 600;
    perspective: 600;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
.card .side {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    -moz-transform-style: perserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: perserve-3d;
    transform-style: perserve-3d;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.card .side.front {
    z-index: 900;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.card:hover .side.front {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card .side.back {
    z-index: 800;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.card:hover .side.back {
    z-index: 800;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<article class="card">
  <section class="side front">front</section>
  <section class="side back">back</section>
</article>
```

Comment: No, the question is which properties (other than all) need transition.